# TypeError: null is not an object for Zeroconf

Tags: react-native, expo, zeroconf

I'm developing React Native for Android, and am using Zeroconf. For the past 2 days, I have been trying to move to Expo SDK 34, and have worked through most of the issues. However, I have run into the following error:

> TypeError: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNZeroconf.scan')
>   -node_modules/react-native-zeroconf/dist/index.js:1:4265 in scan

I did not have this error when running on `Expo SDK 32`. The relevant code bits:

```js
    import Zeroconf from 'react-native-zeroconf'

    componentDidMount(){
       this.zeroconf = new Zeroconf()
       this.startDockScan()
    }

    startDockScan=()=>{
       this.zeroconf.scan('http','tcp','local.'); //this is where the error traces back to
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use this module if you haven't ejected `Expo`.

Because you have to `link` this module to `Android` and `iOS` folders.

1. There are two ways you can solve it. One is to ejecting the `Expo`
   and then `link` module.
2. The other thing is that you can create a project using `React Native`
   and then do it.

First Way to apply `Android`

```
1. Expo eject
2. react-native link react-native-zeroconf
```

Second way to apply `Android`

```
1. react-native init yourproject
2. cd yourproject && yarn add react-native-zeroconf && react-native link react-native-zeroconf
3. and run react-native
```

If you want nothing, you must find another module.

Comment: I have been following the first way throughout development. I resolved this issue by setting up the project again (deleting the Android/iOS + node_module folders, running npm_install, ejecting, and then linking), but have run into other issues since. Upgrading Expo versions is a pain.

Comment: @cfire19045 The issue of upgrading Expo is not the problem you asked for at all Select my answer to end the question and create a new one.